# Esper EPL window select not working for a basic example

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

Everything I read says this should work: I need my listener to trigger every 10 seconds with events. What I am getting now is every event in, it a listener trigger. What am I missing? The basic requirements are to create summarized statistics every 10s. Ideally I just want to pump data into the runtime. So, in this example, I would expect a dump of 10 records, once every 10 seconds

```java
class StreamTest {

    private final Configuration     configuration = new Configuration();
    private final EPRuntime         runtime;
    private final CompilerArguments args          = new CompilerArguments();
    private final EPCompiler        compiler;

    public DatadogApplicationTests() {
        configuration.getCommon().addEventType(CommonLogEntry.class);
        runtime = EPRuntimeProvider.getRuntime(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), configuration);
        args.getPath().add(runtime.getRuntimePath());
        compiler = EPCompilerProvider.getCompiler();
    }
    @Test
    void testDisplayStatsEvery10S() throws Exception{
        //        Display stats every 10s about the traffic during those 10s:

        EPCompiled       compiled         = compiler.compile("select * from CommonLogEntry.win:time(10)", args);

        runtime.getDeploymentService().deploy(compiled).getStatements()[0].addListener(
                (old, newEvents, epStatement, epRuntime) -> 
                 Arrays.stream(old).forEach(e -> System.out.format("%s: received %n", LocalTime.now()))

        );

        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/access.log"))).lines().map(CommonLogEntry::new).forEachOrdered(e -> {
            runtime.getEventService().sendEventBean(e, e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Which currently outputs every second, corresponding to the sleep in my stream:

```
11:00:54.676: received 
11:00:55.684: received 
11:00:56.689: received 
11:00:57.694: received 
11:00:58.698: received 
11:00:59.700: received
```

Answer (score 0):

A time window is a sliding window. There is a chapter on basic concepts that explains how they work. [Here is the link to the basic concepts chapter.](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.4.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#processingmodel)

It is not clear what the requirements are but I think what you want to achieve is collecting events for a while and then releasing them. You can draw inspiration from the [solution patterns](http://www.espertech.com/esper/solution-patterns/).

This will collect events for 10 seconds.

```
create schema StockTick(symbol string, price double);
create context CtxBatch start @now end after 10 seconds;
context CtxBatch select * from StockTick#keepall output snapshot when terminated;
```

Comment: Ok, I will have a look. I will also update with more requirements